# How to Implement Build Solution similar to that of in Visual Studio?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, visual-studio-2017, step-into

What generally happens when we click on Build Solution in IDE(Visual studio) behind the scenes, how does it fetch all the packages,need a mechanism and appropriate datastructures to do it, Can anyone explain the Design and structures?

Also How can one implement step in and step out like feature in visual studio?
how it could have been implemented?

Comment: I'm sorry but I find your question very broad. A valid answer should explain how Visual Studio performs a build and how its debugger steps in an out. This can not be answered in a complete and concise way. Can you narrow your question down to a more concrete problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the project settings, the compiler knows the names and paths of the files to be processed. (The preprocessor finds in every compiled source the files to be included and searches in the paths it knows.)

Similarly, the linker knows the object files it generated as well as the external library files that were specified.

---

For the debugger to be able to perform its work, the compiler and linker add reference information to relate the machine-language instructions and the high-level language statements. When you set a breakpoint, the debugger modifies the instructions locally to temporarily insert an instruction that returns control to the debugger.

This way, the debugger is able to navigate in the high-level source code while executing the compiled code.